# Add title under the icon of navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to add title under the icon that as default appears when i create the navigation drawer .

[like in red border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcLw0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible if you use normal ActionBarToggle, you can provide your own custom layout in toolbar and add menu icon to it but back animation will not work. Also you will have to handle click events on the menu your self

Comment: Thanks for your interest and for your answer